# How do I prepare 2d spectrograms from .wav files for input to a neural network?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, signal-processing, voice-recognition

I have been asked to build a voice recognition system for a conversion masters course and it's a bit beyond my capabilities. I need to prepare wav files for analysis with an RNN but have trouble with the processing part. I have tried to use thinkdsp to convert the wav file into a spectrogram of around 23 ms timeblocks but can't see how I can use the output:

```
times:  [0.011564625850340135, 0.023174603174603174, 0.034784580498866215, 0.046394557823129248, 0.058004535147392289, 0.069614512471655329, 0.08122448979591837, 0.092834467120181396, 0.10444444444444445, 0.11605442176870749, 0.12766439909297053, 0.13927437641723356, 0.15088435374149661, 0.16249433106575964, 0.17410430839002267, 0.18571428571428572, 0.19732426303854878, 0.20893424036281177, 0.22054421768707483, 0.23215419501133788, 0.24376417233560094, 0.25537414965986394, 0.26698412698412699, 0.27859410430839004, 0.29020408163265304, 0.3018140589569161, 0.31342403628117915, 0.32503401360544215, 0.33664399092970521, 0.34825396825396826, 0.35986394557823131, 0.37147392290249431, 0.38308390022675737, 0.39469387755102042, 0.40630385487528342, 0.41791383219954648, 0.42952380952380953, 0.44113378684807258, 0.45274376417233558, 0.46435374149659864, 0.47596371882086169, 0.48757369614512469, 0.49918367346938775, 0.5107936507936508, 0.52240362811791385, 0.53401360544217691, 0.54562358276643996, 0.55723356009070291, 0.56884353741496596, 0.58045351473922902, 0.59206349206349207, 0.60367346938775512, 0.61528344671201818, 0.62689342403628112, 0.63850340136054418, 0.65011337868480723, 0.66172335600907028, 0.67333333333333334, 0.68494331065759639, 0.69655328798185945, 0.7081632653061225, 0.71977324263038545, 0.7313832199546485, 0.74299319727891155, 0.75460317460317461, 0.76621315192743766, 0.77782312925170072, 0.78943310657596366, 0.80104308390022672, 0.81265306122448977, 0.82426303854875282, 0.83587301587301588, 0.84748299319727893, 0.85909297052154199, 0.87070294784580504, 0.88231292517006799]
{0.011564625850340135: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x101a5ecf8>, 0.023174603174603174: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x101a5ee80>, 0.034784580498866215: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba04e10>, 0.046394557823129248: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba04eb8>, 0.058004535147392289: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba04ef0>, 0.069614512471655329: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba04f28>, 0.08122448979591837: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba04f60>, 0.092834467120181396: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba04f98>, 0.10444444444444445: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba04fd0>, 0.11605442176870749: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba21048>, 0.12766439909297053: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba21080>, 0.13927437641723356: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba210b8>, 0.15088435374149661: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba210f0>, 0.16249433106575964: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba21128>, 0.17410430839002267: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba21160>, 0.18571428571428572: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba21198>, 0.19732426303854878: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba211d0>, 0.20893424036281177: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba21208>, 0.22054421768707483: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba21240>, 0.23215419501133788: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba21278>, 0.24376417233560094: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba212b0>, 0.25537414965986394: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba212e8>, 0.26698412698412699: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba21320>, 0.27859410430839004: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba21358>, 0.29020408163265304: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba21390>, 0.3018140589569161: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba213c8>, 0.31342403628117915: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba21400>, 0.32503401360544215: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba21438>, 0.33664399092970521: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba21470>, 0.34825396825396826: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba214a8>, 0.35986394557823131: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba214e0>, 0.37147392290249431: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba21518>, 0.38308390022675737: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba21550>, 0.39469387755102042: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba21588>, 0.40630385487528342: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba215c0>, 0.41791383219954648: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba215f8>, 0.42952380952380953: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba21630>, 0.44113378684807258: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba21668>, 0.45274376417233558: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba216a0>, 0.46435374149659864: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba216d8>, 0.47596371882086169: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba21710>, 0.48757369614512469: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba21748>, 0.49918367346938775: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba21780>, 0.5107936507936508: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba217b8>, 0.52240362811791385: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba217f0>, 0.53401360544217691: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba21828>, 0.54562358276643996: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba21860>, 0.55723356009070291: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba21898>, 0.56884353741496596: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba218d0>, 0.58045351473922902: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba21908>, 0.59206349206349207: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba21940>, 0.60367346938775512: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba21978>, 0.61528344671201818: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba219b0>, 0.62689342403628112: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba219e8>, 0.63850340136054418: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba21a20>, 0.65011337868480723: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba21a58>, 0.66172335600907028: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba21a90>, 0.67333333333333334: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba21ac8>, 0.68494331065759639: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba21b00>, 0.69655328798185945: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba21b38>, 0.7081632653061225: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba21b70>, 0.71977324263038545: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba21ba8>, 0.7313832199546485: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba21be0>, 0.74299319727891155: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba21c18>, 0.75460317460317461: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba21c50>, 0.76621315192743766: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba21c88>, 0.77782312925170072: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba21cc0>, 0.78943310657596366: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba21cf8>, 0.80104308390022672: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba21d30>, 0.81265306122448977: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba21d68>, 0.82426303854875282: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba21da0>, 0.83587301587301588: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba21dd8>, 0.84748299319727893: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba21e10>, 0.85909297052154199: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba21e48>, 0.87070294784580504: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba21e80>, 0.88231292517006799: <thinkdsp.Spectrum object at 0x10ba21eb8>}
frequencies:  [    0.            43.06640625    86.1328125    129.19921875   172.265625
   215.33203125   258.3984375    301.46484375   344.53125      387.59765625
   430.6640625    473.73046875   516.796875     559.86328125   602.9296875
   645.99609375   689.0625       732.12890625   775.1953125    818.26171875
   861.328125     904.39453125   947.4609375    990.52734375  1033.59375
  1076.66015625  1119.7265625   1162.79296875  1205.859375    1248.92578125
  1291.9921875   1335.05859375  1378.125       1421.19140625  1464.2578125
  1507.32421875  1550.390625    1593.45703125  1636.5234375   1679.58984375
  1722.65625     1765.72265625  1808.7890625   1851.85546875  1894.921875
  1937.98828125  1981.0546875   2024.12109375  2067.1875      2110.25390625
  2153.3203125   2196.38671875  2239.453125    2282.51953125  2325.5859375
  2368.65234375  2411.71875     2454.78515625  2497.8515625   2540.91796875
  2583.984375    2627.05078125  2670.1171875   2713.18359375  2756.25
  2799.31640625  2842.3828125   2885.44921875  2928.515625    2971.58203125
  3014.6484375   3057.71484375  3100.78125     3143.84765625  3186.9140625
  3229.98046875  3273.046875    3316.11328125  3359.1796875   3402.24609375
  3445.3125      3488.37890625  3531.4453125   3574.51171875  3617.578125
  3660.64453125  3703.7109375   3746.77734375  3789.84375     3832.91015625
  3875.9765625   3919.04296875  3962.109375    4005.17578125  4048.2421875
  4091.30859375  4134.375       4177.44140625  4220.5078125   4263.57421875
  4306.640625    4349.70703125  4392.7734375   4435.83984375  4478.90625
  4521.97265625  4565.0390625   4608.10546875  4651.171875    4694.23828125
  4737.3046875   4780.37109375  4823.4375      4866.50390625  4909.5703125
  4952.63671875  4995.703125    5038.76953125  5081.8359375   5124.90234375
  5167.96875     5211.03515625  5254.1015625   5297.16796875  5340.234375
  5383.30078125  5426.3671875   5469.43359375  5512.5       ]
```

to make a useful 2 dimensional input vector for an RNN. I would have thought from my reading that I would get a series of spectrum peaks at consecutive times. Could anyone give me an example of what a good input should actually look like? Alternatively I have tried to use the code at https://github.com/baidu-research/ba-dls-deepspeech/blob/master/README.md to preprocess the signal for me but my attempts here using the generate data file just print "Using theano backend." in red before crashing with no other error information. I'd be very grateful for any advice, useful links and tutorials or general assistance anyone can offer. There is a reasonable amount available but it tends to be too advanced and off-topic for my understanding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[librosa](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/index.html) could be a good starting point for audio processing and feature extraction for speech recognition.

```
window_size_sec = 0.025
window_shift_sec = 0.0125
sample_rate = 8000
data, sampling_rate = librosa.core.load('audio.wav', sr=sample_rate, mono=True)
win_length = int(sample_rate * window_size_sec)
hop_length = int(sample_rate * window_shift_sec)
n_fft = win_length # must be >= win_length
spectrogram = librosa.core.stft(data, n_fft=n_fft, hop_length=hop_length, win_length=win_length)

spectrogram.shape
(101, 338)
```

where `shape[0]` is features, `shape[1]` is time, transpose if needed. That number of features may be too high for you, so you could check [MFCC](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.feature.mfcc.html#librosa.feature.mfcc) and other methods.

[scipy.signal.spectrogram](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.spectrogram.html#scipy.signal.spectrogram) is more low-level but may also fit well.

Comment: Thankyou! That's very helpful, so as I undertstand it the features are the k frequency bin magnitudes and the time series ts gives the phase at each window so for spectrogram = [a,b,c,d][x,y,z...] the first frame's input vector for the RNN would be an element of the k x ts matrix [a.exp(ix), b.exp(ix), c.exp(ix), d.exp(ix)] is that right?

Comment: Not sure, it depends on RNN implementations. For example, Tensorflow's `bidirectional_dynamic_rnn` accepts inputs of shape `[batch_size, max_time, num_features]` or `[batch_size, num_features, max_time]` depending on call arguments. `max_time` is the max sequence length, all shorter sequences should be padded.